# Cannot find source for binding

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

My application would throw this error message when I added a new tab and then deleted it:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=TabStripPlacement; DataItem=null; target element is 'TabItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

It didn't complain if I added a new tab, switched to another tab, switched back, and then deleted it. Seemed like something was "updated" during the switches, but I couldn't figure out what and how to fix them.

This is my xaml file:

```
<Window x:Class="MyHomework__MVVM_.MyHomeworkView"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
       Title="My Homework" Height="450" Width="800" ResizeMode="CanMinimize">
    <Grid Margin="0,0,10,10">
        <TabControl HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="330" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="764" Margin="10,10,0,0" ItemsSource="{Binding AllTabs}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab}">
            <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
                <Style TargetType="TabItem">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Header}"/>
                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate">
                        <Setter.Value>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid>
                                    <TextBox Text="{Binding Text, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" FontSize="16" AcceptsReturn="True" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextChanged="OnTextChanged">
                                    </TextBox>
                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </Setter.Value>
                    </Setter>
                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="20"/>
                </Style>
            </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        </TabControl>
        <Button Content="Add Course" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Margin="10,351,0,0" Height="50" Command="{Binding AddCourseCommand}"/>
        <Button Content="Drop Course" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="76" Margin="126,379,0,0" Height="22" Command="{Binding DropCourseCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
        <Button Content="Save HW" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="105" Margin="669,351,0,0" Height="50" Command="{Binding SaveHomeworkCommand, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

And this is my codes for adding/deleting tabs:

```
public void AddNewTab()
        {
            NewCourseName ncn = new NewCourseName();
            ncn.Owner = mainWindow;
            ncn.ShowDialog();
            if (ncn.courseName != null)
            {
                MyHomeworkModel newTab = new MyHomeworkModel();
                newTab.Header = ncn.courseName;
                newTab.Text = "";
                AllTabs.Add(newTab);
                SelectedTab = newTab;
            }
        }

public void RemoveTab()
        {
            DropCourseConfirmation dcc = new DropCourseConfirmation();
            dcc.Owner = mainWindow;
            dcc.ShowDialog();
            if (dcc.drop == true)
            {
                int index = AllTabs.IndexOf(SelectedTab);
                AllTabs.Remove(SelectedTab);

                if (AllTabs.Count > 0)
                {
                    if (index == 0)
                    {
                        SelectedTab = AllTabs[0];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        SelectedTab = AllTabs[--index];
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    SelectedTab = null;
                }
            }
        }
```

Let me know if you need to see more codes. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Nobody wants to help me...?

Comment: Probably nobody knows how to help you, google finds almost nothing about this warning. I just have hit the same issue and posted an analysis below. There is no workaround except replacing the offending default style.

Comment: Just to note: I got exactly the same error with the same pattern of appearance as you mentioned above in some code I wrote for learning WPF. It is helpful to know that one is not alone with such *surprises*! (I am totally new to WPF).

Comment: in my code I wasn't removing TabItems at all, and still had these queer binding errors. Switching from automatically managed TabItems (via `ItemsSource`) to explicit TabItems (actually I had only two of them - a kind of static layout) helped me to get rid of those binding errors :)

Answer (score 25):

As [Zarat](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16367625/138078) mentioned the default style for TabItem in Windows 8 has triggers that fire after the remove and then look for the now missing TabControl. I consider that a bug because adding and removing TabItems is a really common scenario isn't it?

I found as a workaround, that it is possible to remove the template of the TabItem:

```
foreach (var item in TabControl.Items)
{
    var tabitem = item as TabItem;
    // if this is the item to remove
    tabitem.Template = null;
    TabControl.Items.Remove(item);
}
```

That looks ok in my scenario, because I will not use the TabItem any more.

I also tried clearing the triggers collection of the template or clearing the conditons collection of its triggers, but it is not allowed to do that (errors).
Also there does not seem to be a way tot disable the triggers.

Comment: Thank you! This made my day. No more warnings after setting `Template = null` just before removing the tab.

Comment: Unfortunately my tab items are data-bound to a viewModel using Caliburn :(

Comment: Kudos. This answer took me ages to find but is so simple and effective.

Answer (score 7):

It's not a bug, just some noise coming from the WPF binding engine when it updates bindings and notices something went missing. It's unfortunate that it can't be silenced. Maybe its worth reporting on Connect or the MSDN forums, but don't expect any quick reactions.

The message you noticed comes from aero2.normalcolor.xaml - the default styles for Windows 8. If you got VS 2012 SP 2 installed in the default location you can find them here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\Blend\SystemThemes\Wpf

In this file are a few MultiDataTriggers with conditions to check the TabStripPlacement over a RelativeSource, looking for the parent TabControl. So when you remove a TabItem from the TabControl it is possible that the binding engine tries to update the binding and finds the parent missing, logging a warning. Thats entirely ok since the TabItem was removed and you no longer care about the styles (if you were to add it again the bindings would be reevaluated and everything would be fine, too).

Now I don't know why they retrieve the TabStripPlacement over a RelativeSource for Windows 8, since the TabItem itself seems to carry a copy of its parents TabStripPlacement. All the other default styles use that local copy of TabStripPlacement for their bindings. So if you feel adventurous you may want to copy the style into your own resource dictionary and use a "fixed" version during debugging to reduce noise ...

Answer (score 2):

I believe this is the definitive fix, it will work at a XAML level (no code behind) and should work for everyone.

**In your TabControl, add this *ItemContainerStyle***

```
<TabControl ItemContainerStyle="{StaticResource FixTabStripTabItemStyle}"/>
```

**And add this *Style* and this *ControlTemplate* to your window/app resources**

```
<!--This should be used whenever a TabControl is using ItemsSource, as some Bindings are failing when the tabs are removed/added-->
<Style x:Key="FixTabStripTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="60" />
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource FixTabStripTabItemControlTemplate}"/>
</Style>

<ControlTemplate x:Key="FixTabStripTabItemControlTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Grid x:Name="templateRoot" SnapsToDevicePixels="True">
        <Border x:Name="mainBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" Margin="0">
            <Border x:Name="innerBorder" BorderBrush="#FFACACAC" BorderThickness="1,1,1,0" Background="White" Margin="-1" Opacity="0"/>
        </Border>
        <ContentPresenter x:Name="contentPresenter" ContentTemplate="{TemplateBinding HeaderTemplate}" Content="{TemplateBinding Header}" ContentStringFormat="{TemplateBinding HeaderStringFormat}" ContentSource="Header" Focusable="False" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding HorizontalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}" Margin="{TemplateBinding Padding}" RecognizesAccessKey="True" SnapsToDevicePixels="{TemplateBinding SnapsToDevicePixels}" VerticalAlignment="{Binding VerticalContentAlignment, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type ItemsControl}}}"/>
    </Grid>
    <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsMouseOver, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0,1" StartPoint="0,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFECF4FC" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="#FFDCECFC" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FF7EB4EA"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="contentPresenter" Value="0.56"/>
            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFF0F0F0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderBrush" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="#FFD9D9D9"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Left"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,0,-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,0,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Bottom"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,0,-2,-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,0,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Right"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="0,-2,-2,-2"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="0,1,1,1"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="false"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
        <MultiDataTrigger>
            <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding IsSelected, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}" Value="true"/>
                <Condition Binding="{Binding TabStripPlacement, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorLevel=1, AncestorType={x:Type TabControl}}}" Value="Top"/>
            </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
            <Setter Property="Panel.ZIndex" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="-2,-2,-2,0"/>
            <Setter Property="Opacity" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="innerBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
            <Setter Property="BorderThickness" TargetName="mainBorder" Value="1,1,1,0"/>
        </MultiDataTrigger>
    </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
</ControlTemplate>
```

Comment: Can you explain your answer in detail? Why are you using ``DynamicResource``?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, I placed my styles in the app.xaml file and that took care of it, I am no longer getting those binding errors. Hope that helps.