# "properties" is not defined?

Tags: c#, wpf

I was trying to follow this tutorial on user settings:

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/patrickdanino/archive/2008/07/23/user-settings-in-wpf.aspx

I defined a setting whose name was Selected, type int, scope user. In App.xaml, I had:

```
<Application.Resources>
        <properties:Selected x:Key="Selected"/>
    </Application.Resources>
```

However I got this error message:

"The namespace prefix "properties" is not defined"

I couldn't figure out why...Any suggestions are welcome.

PS. If you could take a look at another question of mine, it would be great! :)

[Cannot find source for binding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419248/cannot-find-source-for-binding)

Edit:
Solved!

Comment: What's the rest of App.xaml look like? the error would indicate there is not namespace declaration like xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties" in the Application tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make sure the properties namespace is defined somewhere, as shown in the example you linked:

```
<Application x:Class="SampleApp.App"
   xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
   xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
   xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties"
   Exit="OnExit"
   StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
     <Application.Resources>
         <properties:Settings x:Key="Settings" />
     </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Notice the line: `xmlns:properties="clr-namespace:SampleApp.Properties"`

You may need to recompile before this error goes away.