# Databinding working, but output window states databinding error

Tags: wpf

I have a `ComboBox` which is bound to an `ObservableCollection` on my viewmodel. The type of objects in this collection are `LanguageItem` objects. I have a `DataTemplate` inside the `ComboBox`'s `ItemTemplate` to customize the UI.

In here, I have a `StackPanel` that has a couple of controls. These controls bind to some properties within the `LanguageItem` object. Everything is working correctly.

This is where the error starts. I have two styles, one on the `StackPanel` and one on a `TextBlock`. These only contain some triggers to change some colours based on the value of `ComboBoxItem.IsHighlighted`. Two `DataTriggers` on each, one for true, and one for false.

Now, since the `DataContext` for each `ComboBoxItem` will be one of my `LanguageItem` objects, to get to the `IsHighlighted` property I use a `RelativeSource` for the binding in my data triggers. Here's an example:

```
<DataTrigger Value="True" 
             Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted, 
                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, 
                                               AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}}">
```

When I run my application, this does work and the colours are set correctly when I mouse-over different items in the `ComboBox`. But in the output window on Visual Studio, I can see the databinding errors logged. Here's an example:

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : 
Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor,
AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem', AncestorLevel='1''. 
BindingExpression:Path=IsHighlighted; DataItem=null; 
target element is 'TextBlock' (Name=''); 
target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

I don't understand why this error is being logged if the bindings are working. At first I was sceptial that these error messages were refering to these bindings. I commented out the two styles, and the errors disappeared. But so did the changing of colours on mouse over, as expected.

Am I lacking understanding of something, or is this a bug in VS? For reference, here's a complete style. I'm targetting .NET 3.0 using VS 2012 with Update 4.

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type model:LanguageItem}">

    ...

    <StackPanel.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Value="True"
                             Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted,
                                               RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TitleBrush}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Value="False"
                    Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted,
                                      RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}}">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </StackPanel.Style>

    ...

</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14419248/cannot-find-source-for-binding   check it

Comment: The order that binding happens is not really in you control.  I get this problem with multivalue converter.  But the converter is called again later with all bindings.

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing the `DataContext` becomes out of scope at some point. If the DataBinding works, this shouldn't be an issue.
Though, to get rid of the error, you can set a FallbackValue when it can't find it:

```
<StackPanel.Style>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type StackPanel}">
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource BackgroundBrush}"/>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <DataTrigger Value="True"
                         Binding="{Binding Path=IsHighlighted, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ComboBoxItem}}, FallbackValue=False}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource TitleBrush}"/>
            </DataTrigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</StackPanel.Style>
```

Also, I would like to note that you do not need to satisfy both True/False conditions for a 2-state DataTrigger. Only having one condition, while setting the 'default' condition is good enough.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Setting the FallBackValue replaces the red error to a yellow warning in the output window, with the exact same message. I'm fairly confident that it doesn't go out of scope. This ComboBox is always displayed on the toolbar on the app. But I'm going to check. I didn't know that about the triggers, and have updated them.