# Binding Errors with WPF TabControl

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, .net-core

I have the following XAML...

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Name="customerTab"
                    ItemsSource="{ Binding DetailViewModels }" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="*" Visibility="{Binding HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <Button Command="{Binding CloseCommand}" Style="{StaticResource closeButtonStyle}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

Basically, I have a listview where I can click on a record to view detail. The detail record gets displayed in the tab control.

You can see I have a button which is bound to a command that closes the tab.

When I close the tab, the following binding error displays...

```
System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=TabStripPlacement; DataItem=null; target element is 'TabItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')
```

I am not totally sure of the issue. Does this mean that the detail viewmodels cannot climb back up the hierarchy to the tab control when it closes?

The actual application works as designed, I just want to address this error so it does not keep coming up every time I close a tab.

The CloseCommand is a delegate command. Here is that code along with the method that it runs.

```
public DelegateCommand CloseCommand { get; private set; }
CloseCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnClose);
public void OnClose()
        {
            OnTabClosed?.Invoke(InstanceId);
        }
```

OnTabClosed is an action that closes the tab and the InstanceId is simply a GUID of the detail viewmodel.

I did search online and found a way to hide the message, but I am disinclined to do that for fear of hiding more legitimate binding errors.

How do I fix this? What is the best way to debug?

**Edit**
Here is the code that handles the closing of the tab item...

```
private void HandleTabClosed(Guid instanceId)
        {
            DetailViewModels.Remove(DetailViewModels.First(vm => vm.InstanceId == instanceId));
        }
```

Comment: If I understand, you are not closing TabControl, but one of TabItems ? Could you show the code closing the TabItem?Then, can you say on which binding you have error?

Comment: I added the code that handles the closing of the tab item. All it does is remove the detail viewmodel.

Comment: according to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21001501/536172), you should nullify `Template` for the TabItem before removing it from TabControl's Items, but I'm not sure how this can be handled in your MVVM-style solution

Answer (score 1):

I just made the test, and I find no error, but I do it a bit differently, so hope will be good for you :

In XAML, I use a "Tag" for buttons (very useful when you use templates).

Taking your code, that would be something like that :

```
<TabControl Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Grid.RowSpan="2"
                    Name="customerTab"
                    ItemsSource="{ Binding DetailViewModels }" 
                    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedDetailViewModel, Mode=TwoWay}"
                    TabStripPlacement="Top">
            <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Title}" />
                        <TextBlock Text="*" Visibility="{Binding HasChanges, Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}" />
                        <Button  Content="X" Click="Button_Click" Tag="{Binding InstanceId}" />
                    </StackPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
        </TabControl>
```

Then on my "OnClick" event I will look which Instance I may remove, then remove it :

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Button item = (Button)sender;
    long instanceId = (long)item.Tag;
    GroupResults selectedGroup = this.MyFullList.FirstOrDefault(x => x.InstanceId == instanceId);
    if(selectedGroup!=null)
    {
        this.MyFullList.Remove(selectedGroup);
    }
}
```

It's not really the same way as you did, but it works fine. I always use Tags when I work on templates, and until now never got any problem.