# WPF TabControl binding error: why does setting the Template with DynamicResource fixes it?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

This is a simple WPF application with a single window.

MainWindow.xaml

```xml
<Window
    x:Class="TestsWpf.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    Title="MainWindow"
    Width="800"
    Height="450"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <local:MainViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>

    <DockPanel>
        <ListView
            x:Name="listView"
            DisplayMemberPath="Name"
            DockPanel.Dock="Left"
            ItemsSource="{Binding Elements}" />
        <TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedItem.Tags, ElementName=listView}" />
    </DockPanel>
</Window>
```

MainWindow.xaml.cs

```cs
public partial class MainWindow
{
    public MainWindow() => InitializeComponent();
}

public class MainViewModel
{
    public IEnumerable<Element> Elements { get; } = new List<Element>()
    {
        new("Element 1", new List<string>(){ "Tag1", }),
        new("Element 2", new List<string>(){ "Tag1", "Tag2", }),
        new("Element 3", new List<string>(){ "Tag1", "Tag2", "Tag3" }),
    };
}

public class Element
{
    public Element(string name, IEnumerable<string> tags)
    {
        Name = name;
        Tags = tags;
    }

    public string Name { get; }
    public IEnumerable<string> Tags { get; }
}
```

When changing the selection of the ListView, the TabControl generates this binding error:
`System.Windows.Data Error: 4 : Cannot find source for binding with reference 'RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType='System.Windows.Controls.TabControl', AncestorLevel='1''. BindingExpression:Path=TabStripPlacement; DataItem=null; target element is 'TabItem' (Name=''); target property is 'NoTarget' (type 'Object')`

A [possible solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69436947/11718061) is to restyle TabItems and set their Template using a `DynamicResource`.

```xml
<Style x:Key="FixTabStripTabItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <Setter Property="Template" Value="{DynamicResource DefaultTabItemTemplate}" />
</Style>
<ControlTemplate x:Key="DefaultTabItemTemplate" TargetType="{x:Type TabItem}">
    <!-- ... -->
</ControlTemplate>
```

However the original author didn't explain why using `DynamicResource` fixes the problem.

My guess is that it allows the Template property to be `null`.

Why does that solution works, and is there any other solution that doesn't require copying Microsoft's default ControlTemplate for TabItems?